# Sharing entities between aplications in Play Framework 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a set of applications sharing the same database.

One which is for reporting, another where the user will use and the last for a system where we import clients via spreadsheets.

They all need the same entities for correct functioning, and at the time they all have the package models.entities.

Except that if i need to change an entity in an app, it obliges me to change the other to avoid the conflict.

Could I solve this by creating a module on PLAY where i would store only those entities?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a module that contains all your models classes an use this module in all your apps